While using Kamal Deploy, in China, Docker pull shows timeout on all images
I have access to our company server in China using SSH. (Ubuntu 24.04)
Up until today, I have been able to use Kamal Deploy to deploy our application just fine.
Now I receive this error:
docker stderr: error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: dial tcp 69.63.186.30:443: i/o timeout
None of the images pull and all retry to failure.
I can deploy or pull just fine in the USA, but not to China. Which leads me to believe the docker registry was recently blocked in China.
What can I do to deploy this software remotely? I do still have SSH access.

My solution:
Following the guidance from here
https://github.com/basecamp/kamal/discussions/510#discussioncomment-7921108
Build the docker image locally, then upload to the server using SFTP.
Removed the old docker container manually, then run kamal deploy
